# Derivative of vector expression with min

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Let vector $f(v) = v*\min(v)$, where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose we want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v_n}\Big)$. How would we take the derivative of the $\min(v)$ function?

(Would the derivative not exist, since $\min(\cdot)$ is not a continuous function?)

Comment: You mentioned a vector u, is it supposed to be in this problem?

Comment: Sorry, it shouldn't be. Thanks for catching that; I originally had $u = v*\min(v)$ instead of $f(v) = v*\min(v)$.

Comment: Gotcha $\quad \quad$